# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.measure(int, int)' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, android-layout, nullpointerexception

I am trying to use

https://github.com/nisrulz/screenshott

library to take screenshot.

But it gives error.

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.measure(int,
> int)' on a null object reference

Relativelayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="x.y.z"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/layoutview">

    <!--
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adViewChat2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="x">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>


-->

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="English"
        android:background="@drawable/shape"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"

        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_15sdp"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_15sdp"
        android:textAlignment="center"

        android:id="@+id/textviewtop"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textStyle="bold"


        />




    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linear"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textviewtop"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
        >
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_15sdp"
            android:background="@drawable/shape"

            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_15sdp"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_15sdp"
            >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="@string/welcome"
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_15sdp"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_15sdp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape"
        android:id="@+id/linear">



        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_weight="0.9"
            android:hint="Write a message"
            android:textColorHint="#A4A4A4"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="send"
            android:id="@+id/btn_send"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"

            />

    </LinearLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```

in `OnCreate` Method:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
View myView =(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutview);
Bitmap bitmap_view = 
    ScreenShott.getInstance().takeScreenShotOfView(myView); // problematic line, this line gives the error.
```

How can I solve my problem? How can I get relative layout view?

Comment: try replacing findViewById(R.id.layoutview); with findViewById(R.layout.layoutView);

Comment: No, your solution is not working.

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace? It's hard to tell what's wrong without it.

Comment: Try debugging and see if `myView` is null or not. If it is null, then it either does not exist in your layout, or, something is happening inside the library that I cannot quite tell without you posting the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

You must don't it in `onCreate`. In this `onCreate` method, your layout is measured and inflated but your UI is not yet created.

You must call your code later than `onCreate`. for example in a button event:

```
Button capture_screenshot = findViewById(R.id.button_takeshoot);
        capture_screenshot.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                View myView =(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutview);
                Bitmap bitmap_view = ScreenShott.getInstance().takeScreenShotOfView(myView);
            }
        });
```

[check Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html)

Comment: What do you mean by "layout measured", "layout inflated", "UI not created"? UI is defined by layout, it's created when layout is created. Views are inflated by `setContentView`. But it's *not* measured immediately. The order is important.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take a screenshot after view drawing
so you need a listener when view drawing is done
you can use **ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener**

```
    ViewTreeObserver observer  = view.getViewTreeObserver();
    observer .addOnGlobalLayoutListener (new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            Bitmap bitmap_view = ScreenShott.getInstance().takeScreenShotOfView(view);

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                view.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            } else {
                view.getViewTreeObserver() .removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: symbol 'view' is the name of my view but in your code put your view name for example 'myView'

Answer (score 0):

This wont give you NPE but SS:

**Kotlin:**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: this method invoke")
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_ss)

        val rootView = window.decorView.rootView
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: rootView$rootView")

        val bitmap = ScreenShott.getInstance().takeScreenShotOfJustView(rootView)
    }
```

**Java:**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_ss);

        View rootView = findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView();
        Bitmap bitmap = ScreenShott.getInstance().takeScreenShotOfJustView(rootView);
    }
```

P.S: I have used the same lib as mentioned above and not getting NPE

Comment: You're using `takeScreenShotOfJustView` what's the difference from `takeScreenShotOfView` in question?

Answer (score 0):

You can try `.takeScreenShotOfJustView(view)` instead of `.takeScreenShotOfView(view)` 
So, use

```
Bitmap bitmap_view = 
    ScreenShott.getInstance().takeScreenShotOfJustView(myView);
```

This will take the screenshot without constraints...

Answer (score -1):

please write like this `RelativeLayout myView = findViewById(R.id.layoutview);`
hoping that the name of the xml layout file is activity_main.xml

Comment: The result is the same in both cases because the function call is the same in both cases: `findViewById(R.id.layoutview)`. Casting to `RelativeLayout` and then back to `View` is ugly, yes, but otherwise does nothing. This should have been a comment promoting code readability instead.